# Installing firebird driver for node

Tags: node.js, firebird

I'm trying to install the firebird driver for node under windows.

When I try npm install firebird, it errors out with the following error:

> 'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I tried downloading the windows experimental build from https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient but that also fails with the following error:

> node test.js
>
> Unable to load shared library C:\firebird\node_modules\firebird\build\release\binding.node

How do I get the firebird driver installed for node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install Firebird client too. README on Github fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Read about their experimantal package for Windows on their [Github](https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient) page, at the 'Under Windows' section.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error and the fbclient is definitely installed.
(even used instclient and it confirmed fbclient.dll in win\sys32)

Error: Unable to load shared library 
D:\node-firebird-win\Release\node_modules\firebird\build\Release\binding.node

Also, don't see a package.json file (guess that's not mandatory).
Tom

---

EDIT:
de-installed, then re-installed Firebird (2.1.4 x64) and all ok now.